# Scraping Content with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm trying to scrape the movie links on this page (http://www.solarmovie.so/watch-pompeii-2014.html) with the CasperJS library. I'm following the tutorial semi-closely (http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#now-let-s-scrape-google).

When I target the anchor children tags of the class I want (.sourceNameCell), only the JSON object gets found, even though I thought I was extracting the anchor value by using ".sourceNameCell > a" as my selector.

I would very much appreciate any feedback you can offer to a budding Javascript-ist!

Please find my code below...

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var links = [];

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.sourceNameCell > a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e;
    });
}
casper.start('http://www.solarmovie.so/watch-pompeii-2014.html', function() {
   this.evaluate(getLinks);
});


casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
    links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
});

casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Comment: the sooner you turn to xpath to use with casper's fetchtext by xpath the better.  Xpath's are the most sure fire way of getting whatever data you need on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Javascript but the tutorial shows "return e.getAttribute('href')". Chris is right about using xpath when you can, css works here ok though.

To clarify my answer:

replace: return e;  (line 7, if counting correctly)

with   : return e.getAttribute('href');

Comment: Please add some example code to your answer. This is not enough information for a good answer.